# How to show today's date at the footer of DatePicker control in WPF using xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currenty working on a WPF application using MVVM architecture style.
While using a DatePicker control facing an issue how to show the today's date at the footer of DatePicker.
Please provide me help.
Thanks

Comment: If i'm not wrong, WPF hasn't got a native DateTimePicker?

Comment: Have you tried the DateTimePicker Property `FooterVisibility` ?

Comment: FooterVisibility is not available.

Comment: Which Control are you using? There is no native DateTimePicker in WPF.

Comment: Are you using the `<DatePicker/>` Control ?

Comment: Yes, I am using <DatePicker/> sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <DatePicker Width="100" Height="10"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**`sys`** Namespace is :

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

You can use above code in your `CustomControl` or directly where required.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure of your question but let's try to help.

First I assume you use the DatePicker from System.Windows.Controls, but it should work for any other component.

What you can do if you really want to display current date under the date picker is this kind of XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DatePicker  SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentDate}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

With this kind of ViewModel:

```
public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }

public DateTime CurrentDate
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

Of course you can use some formatting on date depending on your needs as explain here:
[Data binding formatting to a DateTime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249448/data-binding-formatting-to-a-datetime-column)

But I think a better solution would be to display the current date as the default selection, which would lead to this simple xaml:

```
<DatePicker  SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"/>
```

With this simple ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowVm
{
    public MainWindowVm()
    {
        SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps.